# Problem running syncdb in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-syncdb

I am trying to go through the django docs tutorial and having a problem syncing mysql.  On the command `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error (note I'm running in windows 7):

```
...
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
raise Improperlyconfigured("Error loading Mysqldb module: %s" % e) 
django.core.excepions.Improperlyconfigured: Error loading Mysqldb module: No module named mySQLdb
```

I have initialized the db in setting.py as:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
'NAME': 'mysite',    #the name I gave in Mysql with 'CREATE DATABASE mysite;'                 
'USER': 'root',                      
'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',   # as set in MysqlInstanceConfig
'HOST': '',                     
'PORT': '',
```

So how do I get syncdb to run correctly? What does the missing module error mean and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the python mysql library.
Here is a django-related [guide to do this on windows](http://web-eng-help.blogspot.com/2010/09/install-mysql-5-for-python-26-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [mySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) module.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably haven't installed the Python module that handles the mysql connections. You can install it through the Cheeseshop with pip or easy_install and it's called MySQL-python.