# Problem using easy_install.exe to install pyMySQL for Django

Tags: python, django, path, easy-install

I'm trying to install the pyMySQL module for python so that I can setup Django (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076098/problem-running-syncdb-in-django) previous question).

I can't get `easy_install.exe PyMySQL-0.3-py2.6.egg` to run for the life of me.  Every time I get the error `easy_install.exe not recognized as an internal or external command...`  I've tried adding various directories to my system path including:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;
C:\Python27\Scripts\; 
C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe
C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe PyMySQL-0.3-py2.6.egg
```

What am I missing that is keeping this from executing?(note I'm on windows 7)

Comment: I fixed it by moving the pymysql egg file into the c:\python27\scripts\ directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) first

[edit]
Uh,

```
C:\Users\Robus>easy_install
Yada yada, not found
C:\Python26\Scripts>easy_install
error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified (see --help)
C:\Python26>
```

The next best thing I can think of is - do you, by any chance, have more than one version of python installed? In that case setuptools might have been installed somewhere else

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have. Is there some way to check if it is properly installed?  I've run 'python ez_setup.py setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg' in its containing directory.